# Undefined variable $loop in Laravel Blade loop

Tags: laravel, loops, variables, undefined, laravel-blade

according to the latest laravel blade documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade see "loops") I can "[...] use the loop variable to gain valuable information about the loop[...]".

My laravel version is up to date but inside my foreach loop I can't access the $loop variable. It says "undefined variable $loop".

Example:

```
@foreach( $values["rating"] as $rating )
@if( $loop->iteration == 3 )
-- do something --
@endif
@endforeach
```

Does anyone know a solution for this? Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you get if you do a `{{ print_r($loop) }}` inside the `@foreach`-loop?

Comment: Unfortunately {{ print_r($loop) }} returns nothing.

Comment: Before the loop, you are certain that `$values["rating"]` actually holds a value? So if you just do `{{ print_r($values["rating"]) }}` before the actual loop you get some kind of output?

Comment: Yes, it holds 7 items - so I get 7 "undefined value $loop" warnings.

Comment: are you sure you are have the Laravel 5.3 installed?
the loop is not available in 5.2: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade
please check your composer.json, there might be something like 5.2.*

Comment: got the same issue yesterday...
as it turned out my Lara version was 5.2 ))
so check again your Lara version

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Laravel 5.3, you'll need to re-save your views in order to see the $loop variable take effect as you may be viewing the cached versions. I had the same issue, upgraded, still had the issue, re-saved the view (after modifying) and then $loop worked.