# Laravel 5.2 Blade - Undefined offset: 5 in my loop for

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i'm creating admin of my articles, in my resource EDIT post i have some problems, i would like show all tags of my post that i'm editing, i'm tryng like this:

I created a variable array with all tags id relation with the post edited:

```
 $post_tags[0]->tag_id // it return some id of tag's post
```

Now i would show all tag's post like input checked in my form edit.blade.php

```
    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_tags); $i++)

        @if($all_tags[$i]->id != $post_tags[$i]->tag_id)
           <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id=" {{$all_tags[$i]->slug}}" value="{{$all_tags[$i]->id}}" data-parsley-mincheck="2"  class="flat"/>
        @else
           <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id="{{$all_tags[$i]->slug}}" value="{{$all_tags[$i]->id}}" data-parsley-mincheck="2"  class="flat" checked/> 
    @endif

 @endfor
```

> **But i'm getting this error:**
>
> ErrorException in Collection.php line 1187: Undefined offset: 5 (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sofis\resources\views\admin\post\edit.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve [Samsquanch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485418/samsquanch)'s answer to match with versions lesser than 5.3. You can access array index by defining `$key` in `foreach()` like shown bellow.

```
@foreach ($all_tags as $key => $tag)
    <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id=" {{$tag->slug}}" value="{{$tag->id}}" data-parsley-mincheck="2"  class="flat" {{ (isset($post_tags[$key]) && $post_tags[$key]->tag_id == $tag->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
@endforeach
```

Comment: yup! like this it work, but my issue is that array '$post_tags' have only 5 elements, and '$all_tag' are more than 5, so my loop check ONLY the first 5 elements and not the others. However the answer to fix the error it's right.

Comment: Yes whenever you access array indexes dynamically such as in a `foreach()` loop, it's a good practice to check the if the key exists in the given array.

Answer (score 3):

**Larvael 5.3 and above**

As others have said, you need to check to make sure the index exists. You can also simplify your logic some by using `@foreach` instead of `@for`:

```
@foreach ($all_tags as $tag)
    <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" id=" {{$tag->slug}}" value="{{$tag->id}}" data-parsley-mincheck="2"  class="flat" {{ (isset($post_tags[$loop->index]) && $post_tags[$loop->index]->tag_id == $tag->id) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
@endforeach
```

Comment: it return "Undefined variable: loop"

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.3 is my version

Comment: Did you upgrade from 5.2 by chance? [It looks like others have had similar problems.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566997/undefined-variable-loop-in-laravel-blade-loop)

Comment: i checked, my composer json have this: "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2.0",

Comment: The `$loop` variable is part of the blade templating engine in 5.3, so that shouldn't be a problem. Do you get `Laravel Framework version 5.3.xx` when you run `php artisan --version`?

Comment: Omg sorry i check with artisan command, my version is laravel 5.2.45 :(

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it clear that this is a Laravel 5.3 only answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This means `$post_tags[$i]` doesn't have element with index = 5. You shouldn't use `$array[$index]` method if you're not sure element with this index exists. Or you should check it before use:

```
@if (isset($post_tags[$i]) && $all_tags[$i]->id != $post_tags[$i]->tag_id)
```

Comment: Might need to check if `$post_tags` has an `$i` too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `$post_tags` does not have index 5, so `$post_tags[$i]` fails